# Optional authentication in Nest.js with @nestjs/passport

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, passport.js, nestjs

I have a route that needs to be used by authenticated and unauthenticated users. I use `@UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))` to enable authentication but it prevents any unauthenticated user to access the route (normal).

How can I allow unauthenticated users to also access the route ?

It seems that there's no options that I can pass to `AuthGuard` in order to retrieve them in my passport strategy.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can just create your own [`AuthGuard`](https://github.com/nestjs/passport/blob/master/lib/auth.guard.ts) for example by extending the existing one:

```
export class OptionalJwtAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {

  // Override handleRequest so it never throws an error
  handleRequest(err, user, info, context) {
    return user;
  }

}
```

And then use this one on your controllers instead:

```
@UseGuards(OptionalJwtAuthGuard)
```