# Social Login in NestJS using @AuthGuard, Passport

Tags: node.js, authentication, passport.js, nestjs, passport-twitter

So, I have *almost* finished attempt to implement social login in NestJS powered app. I have some problems though:

First things first. I have `AuthModule` and in there is provider `TwitterGuard`:

```js
const twitterOptions: IStrategyOptionWithRequest = {
  consumerKey: process.env[ENV.SOCIAL.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY],
  consumerSecret: process.env[ENV.SOCIAL.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET],
  callbackURL: process.env[ENV.SOCIAL.TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL],
  passReqToCallback: true,
  includeEmail: true,
  skipExtendedUserProfile: false,
};

export class TwitterGuard extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'twitter') {
  constructor() {
    super(twitterOptions);
  }

  // Magical nest implementation, eq to passport.authenticate
  validate(req: Request, accessToken: string, refreshToken: string, profile: Profile, done: (error: any, user?: any) => void) {
    const user: SocialAuthUser = {
      id: profile.id,
      nick: profile.username,
      name: profile.displayName,
    };
    if (profile.emails) {
      user.email = profile.emails.shift().value;
    }
    if (profile.photos) {
      user.avatar = profile.photos.shift().value;
    }

    done(null, user);
  }
}
```

as well as `AuthController`:

```js
@Controller('auth')
@ApiUseTags('auth')
export class SocialAuthController {

  constructor(private us: UserService) {
  }

  @Get('twitter')
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('twitter'))
  twitter() {
    throw new UnauthorizedException();
  }

  @Get('twitter/callback')
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('twitter'))
  async twitterCallback(@ReqUser() socialUser: SocialAuthUser, @Res() response) {
    const user = await this.us.registerSocialUser(socialUser);
    if (user) {
      // console.log('Redirect', '/some-client-route/token');
      response.redirect(`${SITE_URL}/activate/${user.token}`);
    }
    response.sendStatus(401);
  }

}
```

When I am calling URL `/auth/twitter` the guard kicks in and reroutes to Twitter page asking user to grant access to Twitter app.

If the user grants access, everything is fine, on the callback route (`/auth/twitter/callback`) the `TwitterGuard` kicks in again and processes user in `validate`, stores to `request` and I can access that further in controller. So far so good.

However if user denies access to Twitter app, the guard returns 401 on the callback route even before any of my methods are hit.

I tried to play with `authenticate` method that is called (now commented out in the code) where I could somehow maybe tweak this but have no idea what to return or do. If that is a way to go, how do I redirect from there to twitter auth page like passport strategy does? What to return on callback to keep going and set some flag that access was denied?

Is there any other way to do it? What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: If you have questions what does `@ReqUser()` do, here it is:

```js
export const ReqUser = createParamDecorator((data, req): any => {
  return req.user;
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Nevermind, I found a solution, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56174487/596367) helped a lot. Posting here in case someone else would get into the same trouble.

I created `TwitterAuthGuard`:

```js
export class TwitterAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('twitter') {
  handleRequest(err, user, info, context) {
    return user;
  }
}
```

and used it at callback route:

```js
  @Get('twitter/callback')
  @UseGuards(TwitterAuthGuard)
  async twitterCallback(@ReqUser() socialUser: SocialAuthUser, @Res() response) {
    if (socialUser) {
      const user = await this.us.registerSocialUser(socialUser);
      if (user) {
        response.redirect(`...url`);
        return;
      }
    }
    response.redirect(SocialAuthController.authFailedUrl(LoginMethod.TWITTER));
  }
```

Now, when Twitter calls the callback route, it gets into `TwitterAuthGuard` `handleRequest` method.

If the access was granted, `user` parameter contains data from user profile and is passed further down the chain to `TwitterGuard` `validate` method (see above in the question).

If the access was denied then `user` parameter is `false`.

Therefore in the controller callback route method I get either normalized user data or `false` in `user` parameter therefore I can check whether it failed or not and act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

There is a slight improvement you can do by only changing the Guard:

```
// guard
@Injectable()
export class FacebookGuard extends AuthGuard('facebook') {
    
  handleRequest<TUser = any>(err: any, user: any, info: any, context: ExecutionContext, status?: any): TUser {
// check for permissions error and redirect
    if(info.message == 'Permissions error'){
      const ctx = context.switchToHttp()
      const res = ctx.getResponse<Response>()
      res.redirect('url...')
    }
    // returns the request
    return super.handleRequest(err, user, info, context, status)
  }
}
```

This way there is no need to check for the user on the controller.